# parse xml file when element contains smth. special with python

Tags: python, xml

i would like to parse an XML file and write some parts into a csv file. I will do it with python. I am pretty new to programming and XML. I read a lot, but i couldn't found a useful example for my problem.

My XML file looks like this:

```
<Host name="1.1.1.1">
   <Properties>
      <tag name="id">1</tag>
      <tag name="os">windows</tag>
      <tag name="ip">1.11.111.1</tag>
   </Properties>
   <Report id="123">
      <output>
         Host is configured to get updates from another server.

         Update status:
            last detected: 2015-12-02 18:48:28
            last downloaded: 2015-11-17 12:34:22
            last installed: 2015-11-23 01:05:32

         Automatic settings:.....
       </output>
    </Report>
    <Report id="123">
       <output>
          Host is configured to get updates from another server.

          Environment Options:

          Automatic settings:.....
       </output>
    </Report>
</Host>
```

My XML file contains 500 of this entries! I just want to parse XML blocks where the output contains **Update status**, because i want to write the 3 dates (last detected, last downloaded and last installed in my CSV file. I would also add the id, os and ip.

I tried it with ElementTree library but i am not able to filter element.text where the output contains Update status. For the moment i am able to extract all text and attributes from the whole file but i am not able to filter blocks where my output contains Update status, last detected, last downloaded or last installed.

Can anyone give some advice how to achieve this?

*desired output:*

```
id:1
os:windows 
ip:1.11.111.1 
last detected: 2015-12-02 18:48:28
last downloaded: 2015-11-17 12:34:22 
last installed:2015-11-23 01:05:32
```

all of this infos written in a .csv file

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# open csv file for writing
data = open('test.csv', 'w')

# create csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(data)

# filter xml file
for tag in root.findall(".Host/Properties/tag[@name='ip']"):print(tag.text) # gives all ip's from whole xml 
for output in root.iter('output'):print(plugin.text) # gives all outputs from whole xml
data.close()
```

Best regards

Comment: After "Update status:" will there always be 3 lines, or is it variable?

Comment: there will always be 3 lines

Comment: Could you please include the desired output?

Comment: *"I tried it with ElementTree library but i am not able to filter element.text where the output contains Update status."* - That's a good start. Please show that bit of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's relatively straightforward when you start at the `<Host>` element and work your way down.

Iterate all the nodes, but only output something when the substring `"Update status:"` occurs in the value of `<output>`:

```
for host in tree.iter("Host"):
    host_id = host.find('./Properties/tag[@name="id"]')
    host_os = host.find('./Properties/tag[@name="os"]')
    host_ip = host.find('./Properties/tag[@name="ip"]')

    for output in host.iter("output"):
        if output.text is not None and "Update status:" in output.text:
            print("id:" + host_id.text)
            print("os:" + host_os.text)
            print("ip:" + host_ip.text)

            for line in output.text.splitlines():
                if ("last detected:" in line or
                    "last downloaded" in line or
                    "last installed"  in line):
                    print(line.strip())
```

outputs this for your sample XML:

```
id:1
os:windows
ip:1.11.111.1
last detected: 2015-12-02 18:48:28
last downloaded: 2015-11-17 12:34:22
last installed: 2015-11-23 01:05:32
```

Minor point: That's not really CSV, so writing that to a *.csv file as-is wouldn't be very clean.

Comment: thanks for that, i will try it out and play around with this. I tried to filter against something but didn't know against what and so on...

Comment: Sure. Tell me how it goes!

Comment: i get following error: if "Update status:" in output.text:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable. The reason is, because i have some "os" entires which are empty and they get a NoneType.

Comment: Well... I'd say, change `if` statement so it can handle this situation.

Comment: I tried, but i guess the problem is at another point. Search is going on.

Comment: Huh? How can the problem be at another point? (What did you change the `if` statement to?)

Comment: I found it!!!!!I tested yours, that worked, so i changed some things in the xml and the srcipt. The problem at the line before:  if "Update status:" in output.text. I changed it to: if output.text is not None and "Update status:" in output.text:

Comment: Perfect. that's exactly right. :) I'll put it in my answer.